# Regex shows only one size of many

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to show the sizes available on a website but I only want to show '`Size x`', x being the number. How would I go about doing this? This is what it's producing:

```
[ 'title="Select Size 6"',
  'title="Select Size 7"',
  'title="Select Size 7.5"',
  'title="Select Size 8"',
  'title="Select Size 8.5"',
  'title="Select Size 9"',
  'title="Select Size 9.5"',
  'title="Select Size 10"',
  'title="Select Size 10.5"',
  'title="Select Size 11"',
  'title="Select Size 11.5"',
  'title="Select Size 12"',
  'title="Select Size 13"' ]
```

Here is the code for the function:

```
function firstShoe() {
        var options = {
            headers: {'user-agent': 'node.js'}
        }
        request('https://www.jdsports.co.uk/product/green-nike-vapormax/281735/', options, function (error, response, body) {
            var sizes = body.match(/title="Select Size [0-9]*.?[0-9]*"/g); //try error
            console.log(sizes);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your current match regex then you can use [grouping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
> const reg = new RegExp(/title="Select (Size [0-9]*.?[0-9]*)"/g);
> let result;
> while ((result = reg.exec(body)) !== null) { console.log(result[1]); }
Size 6
Size 7
Size 7.5
Size 8
Size 8.5
Size 9
Size 9.5
Size 10
Size 10.5
Size 11
Size 11.5
Size 12
Size 13
```

Comment: How would I just log the array as a whole instead of printing them individually?

Comment: You'll need to create an array and `push` to the array in the body of the while loop.